# Is there a way to check if 2D level set function has changed from representing an object of genus 0 to genus 1?

Tags: general-topology, image-processing

This question has been moved from [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23828184/when-using-the-level-set-method-to-represent-moving-interfaces-is-there-a-way-t) to here.

My goal is image segmentation but I think my question is a math one:

In computer vision level sets are regularly used to represent moving interfaces. Often the level set function is defined by a signed distance function (SDF). Sometimes the goal in image segmentation is to delineate an object of genus 0, but levels sets change topology quite easily. My question; is there a way to determine if the topology of a level set function has changed?

Here is a sample problem:

This is the image I'm trying to segment:

[image]

This is my current result (plotting the zero isocontours of the level set function):

[image]

Here is a link to the actual level set function:

[link to final SDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4tggnAyFPDtczNxR2x6Nm41bmc/edit?usp=sharing)

My goal is that the zero level set would consist of just one contour, encircling the galaxy. I want to create a detector function which tells me when the topology changes.

Comment: Your question is to vague to answer mathematically as you haven't defined the terms but usually the study of topology of surfaces using level sets of smooth functions is very common. Its called **Morse theory**. Just have a look at the wiki page, you might get your answer.